# Defining a 1: 0 ...1 relationship in sql command

Tags: sql, sqlcommand, sql-scripts

I want to set up two tables in sql command.

I have a `Customer` table and a `User Account` table.

A `Customer` has none or at most 1 `User_account` (0...1) relationship.

But a `USER_ACCOUNT` will always have a `CUSTOMER`.

How can I do it via SQL command?

**EDIT** Here's what I have tried so far:

```
ALTER TABLE UserAccount DROP CONSTRAINT FKUserAccountToCustomer
GO

DROP TABLE Customer;
DROP TABLE UserAccount;
GO

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    (...)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE UserAccount
(
    UserAccountID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
    (...)
);
GO

ALTER TABLE Customer ADD PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID);
GO

ALTER TABLE UserAccount ADD PRIMARY KEY(UserAccountID);
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysdiagrams WHERE name = 'FKUserAccountToCustomer')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE UserAccount
    ADD CONSTRAINT FKUserAccountToCustomer
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID)
    REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
END;
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: With pleasure, give me a moment.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to create the tables? Or query existing data?

Comment: Done adding an example of my code.

Comment: Ah, ok! Thanks @Philipp, I will correct this right away.

Comment: @Philipp Now is it ok? I have rewrote the post to reflect the needs.

Comment: @musefan I want to create the tables with the foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a customer can have 0 or 1 user account, then make the UserAccount Id the same as the Customer Id, enforced with primary key and foreign key constraints like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
 (
   CustomerId     int  not null identity(1,1)
    constraint PK_Customer
     primary key clustered
   ,(...)
 )

CREATE TABLE UserAccount
 (
   UserAccountId  int  not null
    constraint PK_UserAccount
     primary key clustered
    constraint FK_UserAccount__Customer
     foreign key references Customer (CustomerId)
   ,(...)
 )
```

This way:

- you cannot create a user account without first creating a customer
- you cannot have two or more user accounts assigned to the same CustomerId
- if "your" CustomerId is not in UserAccount, then you have no user account

Comment: Wow! Ok, I will give it a try.

Comment: Interesting :) Seems like this did the job. What does the `clustered` words means?

Comment: Describing clustered vs. non-clustered indexes is a long discussion. Here's the SQL Books Online description: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique constraint to the `CustomerId` in `UserAccount` to ensure that Customer cannot have several account..

Should be doable like this

```
ALTER TABLE UserAccount ADD CONSTRAINT IX_Customer UNIQUE(CustomerId)
```

Comment: Following the way I wrote my script, how would you write it to make it unique? And how would you refer it to Customer?